# Fitbit data in android/iOS application

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth, fitbit

I am newbie to fitbit app integration.

I have a requirement of an application that can access the fitbit data such as heart rate, number of steps, calories in a real time basis.

Can this be implemented

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Fitbit API](https://dev.fitbit.com/) as long as you have network access. You can get realtime data through [subscriptions](https://dev.fitbit.com/docs/subscriptions/). You [cannot interact over bluetooth](https://community.fitbit.com/t5/Web-API/Where-is-the-Bluetooth-SDK-Can-my-app-communicate-directly-with-the-Fitbit/m-p/333948#M70), though.